# Clockwork is not working with Foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, foreman

I am using clockwork gem to send daily emails. I have created clock.rb file inside lib folder.

```
  #clock.rb
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'clockwork'
  include Clockwork

  every(1.day, 'reminders.send', :at => '09:30'){
   @leave_details = LeaveDetail.all(:conditions => {:status => [LeaveDetail::STATUS_PENDING, LeaveDetail::STATUS_PENDING_MNGT]})
   @leave_details.each do |ld|
   UserMailer.leave_reminder_email(ld).deliver
 end
}
```

I have created a Procfile:-

```
web:    bundle exec thin start -d
clock:  bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
```

when i command

```
foreman start
```

it is showing error:-

```
17:20:51 web.1   | started with pid 21144
17:20:51 clock.1 | started with pid 21146
17:20:52 clock.1 | I, [2012-12-06T17:20:52.558231 #21150]  INFO -- : Starting clock for 1 events: [ reminder.deliver ]
17:20:52 clock.1 | I, [2012-12-06T17:20:52.558324 #21150]  INFO -- : Triggering 'reminder.deliver'
17:20:52 clock.1 | E, [2012-12-06T17:20:52.558399 #21150] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant LeaveDetail (NameError)
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/Desktop/14-11-2012/RoR/P10HR/lib/clock.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/clockwork-0.4.1/lib/clockwork.rb:93:in `call'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/clockwork-0.4.1/lib/clockwork.rb:93:in `run'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/clockwork-0.4.1/lib/clockwork.rb:172:in `block in tick'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/clockwork-0.4.1/lib/clockwork.rb:170:in `each'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/clockwork-0.4.1/lib/clockwork.rb:170:in `tick'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/clockwork-0.4.1/lib/clockwork.rb:156:in `block in run'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/clockwork-0.4.1/lib/clockwork.rb:155:in `loop'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/clockwork-0.4.1/lib/clockwork.rb:155:in `run'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/clockwork-0.4.1/bin/clockwork:19:in `<top (required)>'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/bin/clockwork:23:in `load'
17:20:52 clock.1 | /home/akhileshwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/bin/clockwork:23:in `<main>'
17:20:52 web.1   | >> Deleting stale PID file tmp/pids/thin.pid
17:20:52 web.1   | exited with code 0
17:20:52 system  | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
17:20:52 clock.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
```

LeaveDetail is a ruby class inside models.
can anyone please tell me why 'LeaveDetail' is showing uninitialized here?. thnks

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I'm having similar issues understanding how clockwork interacts with the rest of my app.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually loading your app in clockwork. Clockwork is a separate standalone ruby process. If you don't tell it about the rest of your app, it has no idea of its existence and so your error is logical. This is from [sidekiq's clockwork example documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/clockwork.rb):

```
# require boot & environment for a Rails app
require_relative "../config/boot"
require_relative "../config/environment"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `include Clockwork` as the module, add `require './config/boot'`
 and `require './config/environment'`

```
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'
require 'clockwork'

module Clockwork
every(1.day, 'reminders.send', :at => '09:30'){
   @leave_details = LeaveDetail.all(:conditions => {:status => [LeaveDetail::STATUS_PENDING, LeaveDetail::STATUS_PENDING_MNGT]})
   @leave_details.each do |ld|
   UserMailer.leave_reminder_email(ld).deliver
 end
}
end
```

Comment: The docs at https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork do say to put the require boot/environment UNDER the `require 'clockwork'` (if that is the version being used)